# Wine в Knoppix

Tags: debian, usb, wine

Как добавить Вайн в Кноппиксе (последний),если он у меня на флешке, а на винт ставить не охота?

Answer (score 1):

Вот, читай[Knoppix Cheat code](http://hamshack-hack.sourceforge.net/knx-cheat.html)